# Find Minimum Time to Occupy Grid

Tags: algorithm, recursion, artificial-intelligence, dynamic-programming, backtracking

**Problem:**
Consider a patient suffering from skin infection and germs are spreading all over rapidly. Assume that skin surface is scaled as a rectangular grid of size MxN and cells are marked by 0 and 1 where 0 represents non affected region on skin and 1 represents affected region on skin. Germs can move from one cell of grid to another in 4 possible directions (right, left, up, down) but can move to only one cell at a time in one direction and affect that cell in 1 sec. Doctor currently who is treating the patient see's status and wants to know the time left for him to save him before the germs spread all over the skin and patient dies. Can you help to estimate the minimum time taken for the germs to completely occupy skin surface?

**Input:** : Current status of skin. (A matrix of size MxN with 1's and 0's which represents affected and non affected area)

**Output:** : Min time in sec to cover all over the grid.

> **Example:**
>
> **Input:**
>
> [1 1 0 0 1]
> [0 1 1 0 0]
> [0 0 0 0 1]
> [0 1 0 0 0]
>
> **Output:** 2 seconds
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> After 1 sec from input, matrix could be as below
>
> [1 1 1 0 1]
> [1 1 1 0 1]
> [0 1 1 0 1]
> [0 1 1 0 1]
>
> In next sec, matrix is completely filled by 1's

Comment: What have you tried? In which part of your solution are you stuck?

Comment: What are the maximum values of M and N? Do you have a time limit?

Comment: @Ash I am finding difficulty in how to start with problem.

Comment: My initial thought is to generate all next possible states and from there reach to goal. Then calculate min  number of states of all possibilities. If there is any other way please let me know.  I am stuck at this point.

Comment: @Damien M and N could be from 2 to 1000

Comment: Is there a link you could share to an online judge where we can test ideas?

Comment: @גלעדברקן, I don't have any link for online judge. This is actually converted version of an interview question.

Answer (score 2):

I will not present a detailed solution here, but some thoughts that hopefully may help you to write your own program.

1. First step is to determine the kind of algorithm to implement. The optimal way would be to find a simple and fast ad hoc solution for this problem. In the absence of such a solution, for this kind of problems, classical candidates are DFS, BFS, A* ...

As the goal is to find the shortest solution, it seems natural to consider BFS first, as once BFS finds a solution, we know that it is the shortest ones and we can stop the search. However, then, we have to consider avoiding inflation of the nodes, as it would lead not only to a huge calculation time, but also a huge memory.

2. First idea to avoid node inflation is to consider that some `1` cells can only be expended in one another cell. In the posted diagram, for example the cell (0, 0) (top left) can only be expended to cell (1, 0). Then, after this expansion, cell (1, 1) can only move to cell (2, 1). Therefore, we know it would be suboptimal to move cell (1,1) to cell (1,0). Therefore: move such cells first.

In a similar way, once an infected cell is surrounded by other infected cells only, it is no longer necessary to consider it for next moves.

At the end, it would be convenient to have a list of infected cells, together with the number of non-infected cells that each such cell can move to.

3. Another idea to limit the number of nodes is to detect duplicates, as it is likely here that many of them will exist. For that, we have to define a kind of hashing. The used hash function does not need to be 100% efficient, but need to be calculated rapidly, and if possible in a recursive manner. If we obtain B diagram from A diagram by adding a 1-cell at position (i, j), then I propose something like

   `H(B) = H(A)^f(i, j)`
     `f(i, j) = a*(1024*i+j)%b`

Here, I used the fact that N and M are less than 1000.

Each time a new diagram is consider, we have to calculate the corresponding H value and check if it exists already in the set of past diagrams.

Comment: The only viable BFS I can think of is one that continually queues the next possible full states of the board. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean by "next possible full states". My idea is to maintain a list of "1", associated with the number of neighbours equal to 0. Not totally sure it will work. I may be too optimistic. I will try to test it. @גלעדברקן

Comment: If a board is [1 0 0 1 0], there are two next states that could be added to a BFS queue: [1 1 0 1 1] and [1 1 1 1 0]. Of course, with a 1000x1000 board, I'm not sure how practical that is. If it's something else, could you explain the BFS in a bit more detail?

Comment: Basically, it is that. The goal is to limit the number of nodes. Not sure I will succeed, I will try @גלעדברקן

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how far I would get with this in an interview situation. After some thought, rather than considering solutions that store more than one full board state, I would rather consider a greedy priority queue since a strong heuristic for the next zero-cell candidates to fill seems to be:

(1) healthy cells that have the least neighbouring infected cells (but at least one, of course),

```
e.g., choose A over B

1 1 B 0 1
0 1 1 0 0
0 0 A 0 1
0 1 0 0 0
```

and (2) break ties by choosing first the healthy cells that when infected will block the least infected cells.

```
e.g., choose A over B

1 1 1 0 1
1 B 1 0 A
0 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0
```

An interesting observation is that any healthy cell destination can technically be reached in time Manhattan-distance from the nearest infected cell, where the cell leading such a "crawl" continually chooses the single move that brings us closer to the destination. We know that at the same time, though, this same infected-cell "snake" produces new "crawlers" that could reach any equally far or closer neighbours. This makes me wonder if there may be a more efficient way to determine the lower-bound, based on counts of the farthest healthy cells.

Comment: Interesting indeed. The problem then is to prove/check the optimality

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of the multi-agent pathfinding problem (MAPF). There is a ton of recent work on this topic, but earlier modern work is a good starting point for finding optimal solutions to this problem - for instance the [operator decomposition approach](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2529/f40c4f79ef24165dbb1a8327770e37cced2d.pdf).

To do this you would order the agents (germs) 1..k. Then, you would start a search where you generate all possible first moves for germ 1, followed by all possible first moves for germ 2, and so on, where moves for an agent are to stay in place, or to spread to an adjacent unoccupied location. With 4 possible actions for each germ, there are up to 4^k possible actions between complete states. (Partial states occur when you haven't yet assigned actions to all k agents.) The number of actions is exponential, meaning you may run up against resource constraints (time or space) fairly quickly. But, there are *only* 2^(MxN) states possible. (Since agents don't go away, it's actually 2^(MxN-i) where i is the number of initial germs.)

Every time all (k) germs have considered a possible action, you have a new complete state. (And k then increases for the next iteration.) The minimum time left comes from the shallowest complete state which has the grid filled. A bit of brute-force computation will find the shortest solution. (Quite a bit in the case of large grids.)

You could use a BFS to find the first state that is completely filled. But, A* might do much better. As a heuristic, you could consider that all adjacent locations of all cells were filled in each step, and then compute the number of steps required to fill the grid under that model. That gives a lower bound on the time required to fill the full grid.

But, there are many more optimizations. The reason to do operator decomposition is that you could order the moves to take the best moves first and not consider the weaker possibilities (eg all germs don't spread). You could also use a partial-expansion approach (EPEA*) to avoid generating a lot of clearly suboptimal policies for the germs.

If I was asking this as an interview questions I might be looking to see someone formulate the problem (what are actions, what are states), come up with the lower bound on the solution (every germ expands to every adjacent cell), come up with an algorithm, and perhaps analyze how hard the problem is, in order of increasing difficulty.